# How can I add a TITLE to my summarise output in R?

Tags: r, caption

I have the following code using the dplyr package:

```r
Cholesteroldata %>%
  group_by(Genotype) %>%
  summarise(`W Stat` = shapiro.test(Cholesterol)$statistic,
            p.value = shapiro.test(Cholesterol)$p.value)
```

It generates a nice formatted table in a separate window, but I'd like to put either a caption or a header on the table in that output window. Help?

[image]

Comment: Look at `gt` or `kableExtra` or any of the other fancy-table rendering packages. FYI, once you start rendering for "fancy", it ceases to be a `data.frame` that you can operate on.

Comment: Thanks!  found kableExtra and was able to pipe the output from summarise to it:  

Cholesteroldata %>%
  group_by(Genotype) %>%
  summarise(`W Stat` = shapiro.test(Cholesterol)$statistic,
            p.value = shapiro.test(Cholesterol)$p.value) %>%
  kbl(caption = "Shapiro-Wilk test by Genotype") %>%  
  kable_classic_2(full_width = F)

Comment: @NatalieProwse add it as an answer! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I installed kableExtra and was able to pipe the output from summarise to it. Adding kable_classic_2 gave me a nice table, and setting full_width=F ensured it didn't span the width of the window.

```
library("kableExtra")

Cholesteroldata %>% group_by(Genotype) %>% 
summarise(W Stat = shapiro.test(Cholesterol)$statistic, p.value = shapiro.test(Cholesterol)$p.value) %>% 
kbl(caption = "Shapiro-Wilk test by Genotype") %>% 
kable_classic_2(full_width = F)
```